# rm -r only files?

Tags: rm, recursive

Is there an way to remove all the files from the current dir (recursively), keeping the directory structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Try without rm first to see what it will remove:

```
find . -type f
```

Comment: Beat me by about 2 seconds :)

Comment: Alternatife for find: `--delete` (That way it does not need to start rm for each file, so you get less overhead).